# In the Burnside book "Theory of Groups of Finite Order" -- error on page 3?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, permutation-cycles

I just got "Theory of Groups of Finite Order" by Wm S. Burnside (1897,1911).
Googling [ burnside "ac followed by ab" ] gives many links to page 3, Chapter I "On Permutations".  Item 6 says "the permutation (ab) followed by (ac) .. is therefore equivalent to the permutation (abc)."  I agree:
abc
bac after (ab)
bca after (ac), which is (abc)

And then "it may be similarly shewn that (ac) followed by (ab) gives (acb) as the resulting permutation."  I don't agree:
abc
cba after (ac)
cab after (ab), which is also (abc) and not (acb).

Is there somebody that I can sue, or am I off base already on page 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nobody to sue, and you are indeed off base already on page 3.

The permutation you have written down is in fact $(a\ c\ b)$; you have written it in $2$-line notation as
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
a&b&c\\
c&a&b
\end{array}$$
which shows that $a$ is sent to $c$, $c$ is sent to $b$ and $b$ is sent to $a$. So in *cycle* notation this is $(a\ c\ b)$. You seem to be mixing up cycle notation and $1$-line notation, which look the same but aren't.

See [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Notations) for more details on how each notation should be intepreted.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks.   I got 2 downvotes.  Am I in the wrong place?

Comment: Not sure about the latter. But not using MathJax for mathematical expressions tends to attract some downvotes.